# Self Join in Pandas: Merge / Join within the same table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, self-join

I have attached the data here.

[Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYIs8.png)

I need to return a DataFrame containing list of all employees (EmployeeID, first name, middle name, last name), and their manager's first and last name. The columns in the output DataFrame should be: EmployeeID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, ManagerFirstName, ManagerLastName.

Hint: Consider joining the table by itself as managers are employees themselves.

This is code I have so far, which is giving me duplicate records:

```
# Creating data frame from Excel File. Enter the appropriate file path
df = pd.read_excel(Employees)

df_new = df[['EmployeeID', 'ManagerID', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName']].copy()
df_new['ManagerID'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['ManagerID'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
# convert object to int64
df_new['ManagerID'] = df_new['ManagerID'].astype(np.int64)

result = df_new.merge(df_new, left_on='EmployeeID', right_on='ManagerID')

print(result.head())
```

Any help on this would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"EmployeeID":[259,278,204,78,255],
                  "ManagerID":[278,204,78,255,259],
                  "FirstName":["ben","garret","gabe","reuben","gordon"],
                  "MiddleName":["T","R","B","H","L"],
                  "LastName":["miller","vargas","mares","dsa","hee"]})

df['ManagerID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ManagerID'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
df_ = df[["EmployeeID","FirstName","LastName"]]
df_ = df_.rename(columns={"EmployeeID":"ManagerID","FirstName":"ManagerFirstName","LastName":"ManagerLastName"})
out = pd.merge(df,df_,on=["ManagerID"],how="left")
out = out.drop(["ManagerID"],axis=1)
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks very much! I actually tried a similar version of your code before, but for the second dataframe I selected the 'ManagerID' column instead of the 'EmployeeID' column, which was causing issues.